# Python 3.6: How to spawn multiple external exe instances from function(generator) in multiprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, generator, external-process

How to spawn multiple parallel external exe instances from function(generator) `for x1 in x:` in multiprocessing manner(to keep always one exec running per cpu thread)? If there is no method to do it in current pseudo code below, then what other best/simple solutions would be?

Btw after exec instance exit I'll need to get size of file outputed & delete it. 
Code purpose is to find desirable combination of x/y/z parameters,

`os.system` line syntax is incorrect for better readability. Behind `state_x = x1/z1` will be more code like exitcode check, getfilesize and compare, so `x1` `x2` `x3` will be not always passed to variables.

```
x = list(range(1, 300+1))
y = list(range(1, 300+1))
z = list(range(1, 300+1))

state_x = []
state_y = []
state_z = []

import os
for x1 in x:
    for y1 in y:
        for z1 in z:
            os.system("external.exe -x1 -y1 -z1 outfile_x1_y1_z1.out")
            state_x = x1
            state_y = y1
            state_z = z1
```

**UPDATE1**

I simplified code more to be more understandable, replaced `os.system("external.exe...` with `print` so that from shell output it would be more clear what code does.

Disregard that `state_* = []` variables always gets last loop variation from generator, it is just simplified code, and expected result - sign that code works!

Question still same, how to spawn exec/print in multiprocess from looping generator.

```
x = list(range(1,2+1))
y = list(range(3,4+1))
z = list(range(5,6+1))

state_x = []
state_y = []
state_z = []

import os
for x1 in x:
    for y1 in y:
        for z1 in z:
            print (x1,y1,z1)
            state_x = x1
            state_y = y1
            state_z = z1
```

Shell output:

```
==================== RESTART: D:/Python36-32/myscript5.py ==============
1 3 5
1 3 6
1 4 5
1 4 6
2 3 5
2 3 6
2 4 5
2 4 6
>>> state_x
2
>>> state_y
4
>>> state_z
6
>>>
```

**UPDATE2:**

This code below starts external exe multiprocessed if run from IDLE, but I don't get variables `state_x` `state_y` `state_z` passed out of function to global variable. After code is finished I type `state_x` in Python Shell I get returned it empty `[]`.

code:

```
import itertools
import multiprocessing
import os

x = list(range(1,2+1))
y = list(range(3,4+1))
z = list(range(5,6+1))

state_x = []
state_y = []
state_z = []

def do_work(x1, y1, z1):
    os.system("ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n "+str(x1)+"")
    global state_x  
    state_x = x1
    global state_y 
    state_y = y1
    global state_z

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(do_work, itertools.product(range(1,3),range(3,5),range(5,7), repeat=1))
```

Comment: Have you already read [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)?

Comment: @Niayesh Isky sure, and hundreds of SO posts & dozen video tutorials, tried asking at other forums and at irc #python channels.

Answer (score 0):

When you want one process per CPU, often the best approach it to use `multiprocessing.Pool`. I *think* this should do roughly what you want (the exact details of your code's logic are not obvious, since you're overwriting `state_x`/`y`/`z` on each iteration, to no apparent effect).

```
import itertools
import multiprocessing

def do_work(x, y, z):
    # do your per-job stuff here, e.g. make the os.system() call, or whatever

    return result # return whatever value you need the worker to send to the main process

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(do_work, itertools.product(range(1, 301), repeat=3))

    # do stuff with results here
```

A `Pool` created with no arguments will, by default, create one process per CPU core. You can tell it to use a different number of processes if you prefer, but it shouldn't be necessary in most cases.

Comment: code is generator, it produces 2.7mil (300*300*300) results, when `return result` can produce single result so it doesn't fit.  `(range(1, 301), repeat=3)` will have only 903 repeats... Read last sentence in first post, `state_x/y/z` won't be overwritten on each iteration.

Comment: I guess I have no idea what you're doing then. My `itertools.product` output should be exactly equivalent to the nested loop you show. Please give some example code that in some way relates to your actual question.

Comment: @ Blckknght Sorry my beginner mind was confused with that at first, now in a morning it makes sense. `product` does exactly same loop as `for` , so it starts exe in multiprocess as expected, at least in IDLE for now, but it doesn't pass local variables from function to global variables & it doesn't run from .py. Please look at UPDATE2 in first post.

Comment: .py started to run without errors from cmd.exe when  I uninstalled Python 2.7. Still trying to figure out why it doesn't pass variables.